# XCode 4 Does not give output

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch, cocoa, xcode4

I'm following the book of Programming in Objective-C by Stephen G. Kochan. I was trying the code and to improve the class example by myself. I opened a project in Mac OS X / Applications / Command Line Tool and the program executes successfully.

When I opened the project as IOS  / Framework & Library / Cocoa Touch Static Library, XCode separates class and implementation files normally. When I try to compile, XCode says it has built successfully but there is no output in the console.

I just followed the book and I am sure there is nothing wrong about Class or the implementation files. "NSLog(@""); files stays in there". According to the book, files are separated by 3:

1. Interface Part (class part)
2. Implementation Part (Which instances located in)
3. int main (int argc, char *argv[]) part.

But when I open the project as cocoa-static library, I get only 1 *.m file. I cannot add any additional *.m file with add -> new file.

My question is, is there any relative problem with my file structure that I am working on? Should I need also separate implementation part and the main part?

I would really appreciate if someone could help with this probelem. I really got stuck and having struggling to proceed next step of the book because I can not try code examples anymore...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you're trying to run a static library project. You can't do this - you need to make an app that uses your static library to be able to run at and see the output.